# Pyspark - counting particular words in sentences

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science, nltk

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column that contains textual content.

I am trying to count the number of sentences that contain an exclamation mark '!' along with the word "like" and "want".

For example: the column with a row that contains the following sentences:

```
I don't like to sing!
I like to go shopping!
I want to go home!
I like fast food. 
you don't want to!
what does he want?
```

The desired output i'm hoping to achieve would like something like this (only counts the sentences that contain "like" or "want" and "!"):

```
+----+-----+
|word|count|
+----+-----+
|like|   2 |
|want|   2 |
+----+-----+
```

Can someone help me with writing a UDF that can do this? This is what I have written so far, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def convert_a_sentence(a_string):
    sentence = lower(nltk.sent_tokenize(a_string))
    return sentence

df = df.withColumn('a_sentence', convert_a_sentence(df['text']))

df.select(explode('a_sentence').alias('found')).filter(df['a_sentence'].isin('like', 'want', '!').groupBy('found').count().collect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is uni-gram (i.e 1 token), you can just split the sentence by space, then explode, group by, count then filter what you wants

```py
(df
    .withColumn('words', F.split('sentence', ' '))
    .withColumn('word', F.explode('words'))
    .groupBy('word')
    .agg(
        F.count('*').alias('word_cnt')
    )
    .where(F.col('word').isin(['like', 'want']))
    .show()
)

# Output
# +----+--------+
# |word|word_cnt|
# +----+--------+
# |want|       2|
# |like|       3|
# +----+--------+
```

Note #1: you can apply filter before `groupBy`, with [contains](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) function

Note #2: If you ever want to do n-gram instead of "hacking" like above, you can consider using SparkML package with [Tokenizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer)

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='sentence', outputCol="words")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)

# Output
# +----------------------+----------------------------+
# |sentence              |words                       |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+
# |I don't like to sing! |[i, don't, like, to, sing!] |
# |I like to go shopping!|[i, like, to, go, shopping!]|
# |I want to go home!    |[i, want, to, go, home!]    |
# |I like fast food.     |[i, like, fast, food.]      |
# |you don't want to!    |[you, don't, want, to!]     |
# |what does he want?    |[what, does, he, want?]     |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+
```

or [NGram](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#n-gram)

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram

ngram = NGram(n=2, inputCol="words", outputCol="ngrams")
ngramed = ngram.transform(tokenized)

# Output
# +----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------+
# |col                   |words                       |ngrams                                  |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------+
# |I don't like to sing! |[i, don't, like, to, sing!] |[i don't, don't like, like to, to sing!]|
# |I like to go shopping!|[i, like, to, go, shopping!]|[i like, like to, to go, go shopping!]  |
# |I want to go home!    |[i, want, to, go, home!]    |[i want, want to, to go, go home!]      |
# |I like fast food.     |[i, like, fast, food.]      |[i like, like fast, fast food.]         |
# |you don't want to!    |[you, don't, want, to!]     |[you don't, don't want, want to!]       |
# |what does he want?    |[what, does, he, want?]     |[what does, does he, he want?]          |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about pandas or pyspark method but you could do this pretty easily with a function

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

t = """
I don't like to sing!
I like to go shopping!
I want to go home!
I like fast food. 
you don't want to!
what does he want?
"""
sentences = lower(nltk.sent_tokenize(t))
for sentence in sentences:
  if "!" in sentence and "like" in sentence:
    print(f"found in {sentence}")
```

and you should be able to figure out how to count/put it in a table...